# Windows xp install disk returns black screen

Tags: windows, installation, setup

I have an old computer. I want to upgrade to win XP. It has windows 98 installed. When I boot from the cd, it starts to load files. Then 1 minute later it returns a black screen. It didn't even reach the setup screen. I tried many things but didn't work.

Edit:
[This](https://youtu.be/hbfpbhdOJK4) happens. It returns a black screen with a blinking cursor

Comment: The machine probably does not have drivers or BIOS for XP. I am not sure (I have nothing back that far) how you would update drivers and BIOS on the old computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 32-bit? are you using 32-bit-XP? Why even use XP, since support is long gone? Try a 32-bit Linux distro, instead, such as Ubuntu 18.04 or earlier, which is supported until 2023.

Comment: Check if the hardware meets the minimum requirements for WinXP. 233 MHz processor, 64 MB of RAM, 1.5 GB of available hard drive space, and an SVGA-capable video card according to https://kb.iu.edu/d/akma